# shell_plus installed with Django giving error - ImportError: cannot import name 'Type

Tags: python, django, django-extensions

I am getting the following error when trying to launch shell_plus after installing django_extensions. Here are the steps i followed
1-Installed django_extensions using

```
pip install django_extensions
```

2-Added `django_extensions` to installed apps

Then I get the following error

```
$ ./manage.py shell_plus           
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/admin/Development/project/virtual/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/admin/Development/project/virtual/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/admin/Development/project/virtual/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 216, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/Users/admin/Development/project/virtual/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 36, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/admin/Development/project/virtual/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/shell_plus.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django_extensions.management.shells import import_objects
  File "/Users/admin/Development/project/virtual/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/shells.py", line 5, in <module>
    from typing import (  # NOQA
ImportError: cannot import name 'Type'
```

Any suggestions on what might be going wrong ?

Comment: What minor version of Python 3.5 are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.5 comes with its own version of typing module. What is most likely happening is that you have the other typing module specified in your requirements (the one that doesn't include Type class) and its getting picked up by django_extensions instead of the native Python one. Check your installed modules, or try running:

```
pip uninstall typing
```