# Cannot run jupyter from command line on Windows using virtual environment due to import error

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, jupyter

Hello fellow programmers, I just tried to checkout Jupyter Notebook. For that I created a fresh virtual environment using Python 3.5.1 and installed jupyter with `pip3 install jupyter` command as recoomended. But when I tried to run `jupyter notebook` I get the following error

```
(venv) C:\Users\srahman\Desktop\seaborn_test>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\srahman\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\Lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\srahman\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\srahman\Desktop\seaborn_test\venv\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.EXE\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\srahman\desktop\seaborn_test\venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .nbextensions import install_nbextension
  File "c:\users\srahman\desktop\seaborn_test\venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 610, in <module>
    from .extensions import (
  File "c:\users\srahman\desktop\seaborn_test\venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\extensions.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tornado.log import LogFormatter
  File "c:\users\srahman\desktop\seaborn_test\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\log.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tornado.escape import _unicode
  File "c:\users\srahman\desktop\seaborn_test\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\escape.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tornado.util import unicode_type
  File "c:\users\srahman\desktop\seaborn_test\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\util.py", line 21, in <module>
    from typing import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'Type'
```

Here is the list of installed packages on my virtual environment (from `pip list`)

```
Package             Version
------------------- -------
attrs               19.1.0
backcall            0.1.0
bleach              3.1.0
colorama            0.4.1
decorator           4.3.2
defusedxml          0.5.0
entrypoints         0.3
ipykernel           5.1.0
ipython             7.3.0
ipython-genutils    0.2.0
ipywidgets          7.4.2
jedi                0.13.3
Jinja2              2.10
jsonschema          3.0.1
jupyter             1.0.0
jupyter-client      5.2.4
jupyter-console     6.0.0
jupyter-core        4.4.0
MarkupSafe          1.1.1
mistune             0.8.4
nbconvert           5.4.1
nbformat            4.4.0
notebook            5.7.6
pandocfilters       1.4.2
parso               0.3.4
pickleshare         0.7.5
pip                 19.0.3
prometheus-client   0.6.0
prompt-toolkit      2.0.9
Pygments            2.3.1
pyrsistent          0.14.11
python-dateutil     2.8.0
pywinpty            0.5.5
pyzmq               18.0.1
qtconsole           4.4.3
Send2Trash          1.5.0
setuptools          40.8.0
six                 1.12.0
terminado           0.8.1
testpath            0.4.2
tornado             6.0.1
traitlets           4.3.2
wcwidth             0.1.7
webencodings        0.5.1
wheel               0.33.1
widgetsnbextension  3.4.2
win-unicode-console 0.5
```

I have tried deleting the virtual env, recreating one, uninstalling and re-installing couple times. I still get the same error. Could you please help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use anaconda...

Comment: @Krishna. No, I do not want to use Annaconda for a specific reason.

Comment: `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`
`python3 -m pip install jupyter` try this

Comment: @Krishna Does not work either. I tried.

Comment: Is there a good reason you don't want to use anaconda?

Comment: @Krishna Yes. If you do not know the solution then leave it. Thank you for your effort and generosity. Nevertheless,  'I cannot use MS Word on Mac'  - does not mean I will buy a Windows PC to be able to use MS Word. My problem is: 'I cannot use MS Word on my Mac'. Not - 'How shall I be able to use MS Word'.

Comment: There's no specific solution for this. Either you clean your system properly or go back forth test which python version works fine and make a mess of your packages. I suggested anaconda because it installs 100+ packages independent of system libraries or admin privileges and you need to think about anything apart from your real work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shell\_plus installed with Django giving error - ImportError: cannot import name 'Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50072672/shell-plus-installed-with-django-giving-error-importerror-cannot-import-name)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ImportError+%22cannot+import+name+Type%22